# Calling Lua function from string_t

Tags: c++, lua

I have some functions declared and initialized in .lua file. Then, when I receive signal, I read string_t variable with the name of function to call from file. The problem is that I don't know how to push function to stack by its name or call it.

For example:

test.lua

```lua
function iLoveVodka()
    --some text
end

function iLoveFish()
    --another text
end
```

C File:

```
string_t a = "iLoveVodka()"
```

How can i call function from C/C++ code `iLoveVodka()` only by having its name?

Comment: push it on the stack and then call `lua_pcall`

Comment: @Appleshell which function do I have to use to push it into stack?

Comment: If it's a global funciton, `lua_getglobal(state, "iLoveVodka");`, or alternatively push its name on the stack and call `lua_getfield`. (Don't be afraid to explore around http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/#index )

Comment: Also, if you have a chunk of runnable code (like `iLoveVodka()`) as opposed to just the name of the function you can use `luaL_dostring` or the functions it is a macro around to run that chunk of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code that does two things:

- Loads the file "test.lua" from the same directory.
- Tries to call the function `iLoveVodka()`, if it can be found.

You should be able to build this easily enough:

```
  #include <lua.h>
  #include <lauxlib.h>
  #include <lualib.h>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>


   int main( int argc, char *argv[])
   {
      lua_State *l = luaL_newstate ();
      luaL_openlibs (l);

      int error = luaL_dofile (l, "test.lua");
      if (error)
      {
          printf( "Error loading test.lua: %s\n",luaL_checkstring (l, -1) );
          exit(1);
      }

      /**
       * Get the function and call it
       */
      lua_getglobal(l, "iLoveVodka");
      if ( lua_isnil(l,-1) )
      {
          printf("Failed to find global function iLoveVodka\n" );
          exit(1);
      }

      lua_pcall(l,0,0,0);

      /**
       * Cleanup.
       */
      lua_close (l);

      return 0;
  }
```

This can be compiled like this:

```
 gcc -O -o test `pkg-config --libs --cflags lua5.1`  test.c
```

Just define your `iLoveVodka()` function inside `test.lua`, and you should be OK.